# Fatshark Shark Byte throughput

Tags: first-person-view, video-transmitters, fat-shark

Is the data throughput rate of the Fatshark Shark Byte system known i.e. Mbps? This will be interesting to know as it will give us an idea of where the limitations of the system are and where we may see improvements over time.

Comment: Hello! Do you mean Fatshark Byte Frost?

Comment: @ifconfig the Fatshark [Shark Byte](https://www.getfpv.com/fat-shark-shark-byte-digital-hd-video-system.html) is an updated version of Byte Frost which recently came out.

Comment:  Wow that's an unfortunate name then, thanks for the context @JacobB

Comment: Not quite an answer to your question, but maybe this info can be used to help calculate bitrate.  Fat Shark stated that for the Byte Frost system, they were using 27mhz wide channels in the 5.8ghz range.  I assume that is still true for Shark Byte but I don't know for sure.  As a comparison, DJI uses 20mhz wide channels